# Knight's Tour Parberry algorithm: 4 knight's tour merge procedure

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, recursion

I'm implementing [Parberry's](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166218X96000108/1-s2.0-S0166218X96000108-main.pdf?_tid=ad81cc86-7572-408a-b988-c964166a2793&acdnat=1522515886_4fd0334580acf3948f36bea0a83d817c) algorithm for closed Knight's tour problem.

Brief idea of the algorithm: split the board in $4$ parts, find the tour on them recursively then delete $1$ edge in each part and add $4$ edges that 
 will connect each part with two adjacent parts.

At the end of page 5 (of the pdf viewer) the author estimates the time complexity of his algorithm. Namely, he writes: $T(n) = 4 \cdot T(n / 2) + O(1)$.

As I understood, the time complexity on each level of recursion is $O(1)$.

Parberry says nothing about the data structures he uses.

So, my question is:

How do I represent Knight's tour and how to merge $4$ Knight's tours to reach a $O(1)$ on each level of the recursion?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a few data structures? How about a doubly linked list with pointers to both head and tail, for example?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I was thinking about writing a class for Knight's tour representation that will store several data structures such as Arrays and Hash Tables, but I think a single doubly linked list will work much  better here. Thanks for the suggestion I will try to implement it.